# $n$ by $n$ Primally Magic Squares

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, magic-square

(Again copied verbatim from [a September 2009 thread I made](http://forum.projecteuler.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1652%20September%202009%20thread).)

A **Primally Magic Square** (PMS) is exactly like a traditional magic square with a change of criteria. Where a traditional magic square is one where the sum of each row, column, and both diagonals are some number, usually 15 (uses 1-9). By contrast, a PMS is one where all rows, columns, and both diagonals form a prime number. Note: if a number is prime *either* forward or back, it counts.

Example:

$\displaystyle \begin{matrix} 1 & 3 & 7 \\ 3 & 9 & 7 \\ 7 & 7 & 9 \end{matrix}$

137, 397, 977, 797, and 199 are all prime, so this square is a PMS.

How many 3x3 PMS's are there?

How many 4x4 PMS's are there?

How many 5x5 PMS's are there?

How many 9x9 PMS's are there?

Side note: Feel free to calculate the number of PMS's for some other $n$.

Comment: Why are you not interested in 6x6 through 8x8 PMSs? And what about 2x2?

Comment: Is it obvious that there is at least one PMS of each of those size? For 2 by 2 PMS, you can fill a square with ones for example.

Comment: @Matthew: Feel free to calculate those too. :P  @Joel: Given the increasing number of primes as $n$ increases, I think there should be at least one PMS.

Comment: @ El'endia Starman : Doesn't the proportion of primes (among numbers with $n$ digits) decreases as $\frac{9}{n}$ asymptotically?

Comment: @Joel: Yes, but the absolute number of primes increases, so that should compensate for the increasing difficulty of making a PMS.

Comment: @ El'endia Starman: Have you tried writing a program to count them?  This is absolutely doable for at least smaller $n$.

Comment: @Matthew: Hmmm...good point. It HAS been about a year and a half and my programming skills have definitely improved in that time... :P

Comment: On reddit someone did a bruteforce search of the 3by3's [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/f41l3/theres_a_magic_square_prime_of_length_9/) and a commenter found 2 4by4s [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/f41l3/theres_a_magic_square_prime_of_length_9/c1fdrjb).

Comment: @Jacob: Nice links! Those are not quite what I'm going for here though; my condition is merely that each column, row, and diagonal needs to be prime in at least one direction, not both as they did.

Answer (score 0):

Following a comment, let's look at the $2×2$ case.  I shall consider the case where all digits are distinct and to avoid issues with convention, nonzero.

Within these limits we select a set of four digits such as $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  If each of the six two-element permutations generates a prime in either order, we have three primary magic squares apart from rotations and reflections (depending on which element is opposite a given one).

The set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ fails because $42$ and $24$ are both composite, and similarly there cannot be any two even digits, nor the digit $5$ (only two numbers in the 50s are prime and we would need three).  We also cannot have two digits with  residues $1,2\bmod 3$ or two multiples of $3$ (which lead to multiples of $3$), nor specifically $4$ together with $9$ (the odd number $49$ is $7×7$).

Here are the sets that work:

$\{1,3,4,7\}$

And that seems to be it!  Thus three squares (plus trivial operations):

$\begin{array}&1&3\\4&7\end{array}$

$\begin{array}&1&4\\7&3\end{array}$

$\begin{array}&1&7\\3&4\end{array}$